# spring security ldap hidden password attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

is there some problem if the password atribute of my ldap OU is hidden? is there some sort of aditional config i must do in spring security? if i currently have the ldap structure as follows:
[image]

and the test cn password attribute is hidden, how should i configure the spring security to do an ldap authentication?

currently i have it configured as this:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()

            .userDnPatterns(USER_DN_PATTERNS)
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource(contextSource())
            .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("UnicodePwd");
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList(LDAP_URL), BASE_DN);
    contextSource.setUserDn(USER_DN);
    contextSource.setPassword(USER_PASSWORD);
    return contextSource;
}
```

and the DN as this:

```
private static final String USER_DN_PATTERNS  = "OU=Usuarios";
private static final String BASE_DN = "dc=mutualser," + "dc=org";
```

but when i try to authenticate i get a NO_ATTRIBUTE_OR_VAL error (i know for sure that that is the name of the password attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security will asume the password is unicodePwd if its not specified.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=Mutual Ser")
            .contextSource(contextSource());
}
```

will authenticate just fine